# Why does the clothes leave water when twisted or swirled?

Tags: everyday-life, water, surface-tension, centrifugal-force

When we wash clothes and are drying them why we swirl or twist them to remove water i mean anything could have happened but the water leaves out of the cloth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water sits in the space between fibers. When you twist the cloth, you squish the fibers closer together and there is not as much space for the water. So it comes out...

When you spin the cloth, you increase the centrifugal force on the water$^*$ - the water is held between the fibers by things like surface tension, but with enough force you can pull it out.

---

$\small\rm{^*Really~you~move~the~fiber~while~the~water~tries~to~go~in~a~straight~line,~but ~in~the~rotating~frame\\of~reference~it~looks~like~there~is~a~centrifugal~force.}$